# Nginx rewrite url from :port to "login"

Tags: nginx, port, node.js

Good evening 
I am new to nginx i read around and am a bit confused between redirecting and rewrite what i am looking for is a way to change www.abc.com:3000 to www.abc.com/login

```
  location /login {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
    rewrite ^/login/(.*) /$1 break;
    root /folder/subfolder/new/;
    index login.html;
  }
```

What do i need to fix ?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you already have something listening on port 3000, and you want to use nginx to act as a reverse proxy directing `/login` to that port? Or are you using nginx only?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this in the following way.

```
server {
        server_name www.abc.com;
        listen  3000;
        return 301 $scheme://www.abc.com/login;
}

server {
        server_name www.abc.com;
        listen 80;

location /login {
           <you config here>
        }
}
```

The first `server` block you see listens for request on `port 3000` requesting `www.abc.com` and redirects them to `www.abc.com/login`. The second `server` block then listens for requests on `port 80` requesting `www.abc.com` if the `uri` is `login` it is then dealt with by the `location` block `/login`

---

You would tend to use `proxy_pass` if you had an app that you didn't want to expose directly to the internet. In that case you would listen on say port 80 and pass that request internally to port 3000 either on the same server or a different one.